# Volusion and Nivo Slider - Can't get Nivo Slider Themes to Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nivo-slider, volusion

I am using Nivo Slider on Volusion and cannot figure out how to get the arrows and bullets to replace the Prev, Next and the numbers at the bottom of the slider. I have typed in 
 to utilize the theme default but it's not pulling it to the page. The slider is on my homepage aristagifts.com. I followed all the instructions at dev7studios on installing but it didn't work and for some reason volusion wants the css in the css folder and the js in the js folder for the volusion template to accept the slider to work which is different than how dev7 studios suggests the folders be uploaded to your server. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Would really like to add the arrows and bullets to this lovely slider. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to explain the steps in detail, however I feel this will do the trick, and I am at work and don't have alot of time. Please see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xWpQm_LUDc#t=328 it is cued up right around the point where he goes into the CSS settings of those elements. Hope this helps! I'll try to jump on later and explain in detail.